# Are snap apps slow to load?

Tags: repository, snap, desktop-apps

I am having an issue with snap apps that is, I'm noticing that snap apps are taking a lot more time to open compared to repository apps or apps downloaded from app store (not snaps)

Comment: How much is "a lot more time?"

Comment: That soundcloud app auryo taking near about 15 seconds to open...and sometimes it doesn't open with first click too..

Comment: @ShivKamalUpadhaya did you find a soltion to this problem. I am having the same problem in 20.04.